# Default redirect in the subfolder's root is not redirected to index.php

Tags: nginx, redirect

In the root directory, any redirect to `localhost/` is simply redirected to index.php, but if you go inside the `localhost/phone` subdirectory, there's an index.php page too, and as you type `localhost/phone/` you are not redirected to the index.php page. No idea why. This is my server configuration.

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        charset UTF-8;
        index index.html index.php;
        location / {
            root   xyz;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
            rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
            location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|webp)$ {
                expires 365d;
            }
       }
```

I tried to point the directory and added defaults for index.php and it works, but now all the url's inside `/phone/` are showing blank.

```
location /phone {
   index index.html index.php;
}
```

By "showing blank" means that they show a 404 error according to the error log

> 2019/05/08 23:40:58 [error] 26240#14076: *1 CreateFile()
>   "C:\xyz\nginx/xyz/phone/index" failed (2: The system cannot find
>   the file specified), client: ::1, server: localhost, request: "GET
>   /phone/index HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Now the index.php shows a 404 error, what am I doing wrong? Even though the file  is there

Comment: The `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;` statement is probably preventing the `/phone/` URI from working with `index`, as it needs a trailing `/` to search for `index.php` files within subdirectories.

Comment: @RichardSmith yes you are right, I removed that line and it works, any workaround without removing that line will be?

Comment: Under what circumstances do you need to remove the trailing `/`?

Comment: Adding a trail to a URL causes a 404 to some URL's so I removed them @RichardSmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid a trailing `/` for all URIs, but still test for `index.html` and `index.php`, you should avoid using the `index` directive and the `$uri/` term with the `try_files` directive.

One approach is to use a named location to test for PHP files. This location will need your `fastcgi` configuration.

For example:

```
root /path/to/root;

location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) { return 302 /$1; }
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html @php;
}
location @php {
    try_files $uri.php $uri/index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is messing with my `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;` can you do something about that? Everything else seems to work